# Make Angular aware of html already inserted from external code.

Tags: angularjs

In a special app I have the body of my page inserted by a third party lib with `document.body.appendChild` after the bootstraping process which I don't control and because of that angular doesn't compile the body.
The examples I've seen so far use `$compile` before inserting the html into the DOM but in this case the body is already there, how can I make angular recognize the non compiled body?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment after the body is rendered, I'm replacing its contents with a compiled version of the html.

```
# in module's run method after the body is rendered
$('body').html $compile(body_contents) $rootScope
do $rootScope.$apply
```

I don't know if there is a better way where existing html can be 'activated' for angular's use.